# failure to restore backup from deja dup

Tags: backup, deja-dup, restore

I had ubuntu 12.04.1 and I made a backup with deja dup of the home folder in an external hard disk.
Today I installed ubuntu 14.4 and erased the ubuntu 12.04.1. Now I'm trying to restore my back up. First it ask where is the back up to restore, then it ask of what date to restore, and then it starts, after a wile ask for the password. I put the password and it says
Restoring and stays in preparing with out any advancement. Don't show any error, just stays  preparing. The window of details is in white.
I had all my documents... it's very bad for me, all my personal data... lost?
Thanks for any help, Layla.

Comment: 2 years later, Ubuntu 16.04, same issue :(